# Generates a randomized locally-administered unicast MAC address

Tags: bash

This is the first time I've attempted writing something in bash, and would appreciate any feedback or criticism to make it better.

```
#! /bin/bash
macArr=( 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
for ((i=0; i < ${#macArr[@]}; ++i))
do
    let "byte=$RANDOM%255"
    # the first byte must have the least significant bits set to "10" 
    # in order to identify as a locally administered unicast MAC
    if [ $i -eq 0 ];then
        let "byte=(((byte>>1)|1)<<1)"
    fi
    prependZero=$([ $byte -lt 16 ] && echo 1 || echo 0)
    # convert byte from decimal int to hex string
    byte=$(printf "%x" "$byte")
    # uppercase any letters in the string
    macArr[$i]="${byte^^}"
    if [ $prependZero -eq 1 ];then
        macArr[$i]="0${macArr[$i]}"
    fi
done
printf "%s" "${macArr[@]}"
```

Comment: Instead of `$RANDOM%255`, shouldn't that be `$RANDOM%256` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting idea, and pretty good first Bash script.

#### Bash arithmetics

Instead of this:

> ```
> let "byte=$RANDOM%255"
> ```

I find this more readable:

```
((byte = RANDOM % 255))
```

You can use math like this within `((...))`, without `$` of variables, and with spaces around operators to keep the expressions nicely readable.

You can use this in conditions too,
in fact, instead of this:

> ```
> if [ $i -eq 0 ];then
> ```

It's better to write like this:

```
if (( i == 0 )); then
```

And here, this is really awkward, as you are running a sub-shell, and storing the output of `echo` commands:

> ```
> prependZero=$([ $byte -lt 16 ] && echo 1 || echo 0)
> ```

When it could be simply:

```
((prependZero = byte < 16))
```

#### Padding with 0

Since you already use `printf` to convert from integer to hexadecimal,
you can actually use it to 0-pad too:

```
byte=$(printf "%02x" "$byte")
```

This will pad with zeros on the left to make it 2-digits wide

#### Suggested implementation

With the above tips, the script can be simpler and cleaner.

```
#!/bin/bash

macArr=( 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
for ((i = 0; i < ${#macArr[@]}; ++i))
do
    ((byte = RANDOM % 255))

    # the first byte must have the least significant bits set to "10" 
    # in order to identify as a locally administered unicast MAC
    if (( i == 0 )); then
        ((byte = ((byte >> 1) | 1) << 1))
    fi

    # convert byte from decimal int to hex string
    byte=$(printf "%02x" "$byte")

    # uppercase any letters in the string
    macArr[$i]="${byte^^}"
done
printf "%s" "${macArr[@]}"
```

Comment: awesome advice, thank you very much.  i'm learning a lot today.